# SomeList<T> : List<T> can't be cast as List<T>?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface

See comment in Main(). Why can't I perform the following?

```
   public class SomeList<T> : List<T>
{
    public SomeList(List<T> existing)
    {
        foreach (var item in existing)
            Add(item);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "I'm a better list.";
    }
}

internal interface IReadStuff<T>
{
    List<T> ReadStuff();
}

public class ReaderStrategy<Foo> : IReadStuff<Foo>
{
    public List<Foo> ReadStuff()
    {
        return new List<Foo>();
    }
}

public class Foo {}

public class Main
{
    public Main()
    {
        var reader = new ReaderStrategy<Foo>();

        // This works, but type is List<Foo>, not SomeList<Foo>
        List<Foo> aList = reader.ReadStuff();
        // This does not compile, but is what I want to do:
        SomeList<Foo> aBetterList = reader.ReadStuff();
        // This compiles, but always generates null for aBetterList:
        SomeList<Foo> anotherBetterList = reader.ReadStuff() as SomeList<Foo>;
        // This is funky but works:
        SomeList<Foo> works = new SomeList<Foo>(reader.ReadStuff());
    }
}
```

I am struggling understanding how to use generics with inherited types. I have a need for the above because I want to extend the functionality of `List<T>` is some special way, for example see `SomeList<T> overrides ToString()`. However, I want to keep my factory strategy using .Net generic `List<T>`. Is there a way to make this work?

**Edit**

I added a constructor that accepts `List<T>` and adds to `SomeList<T>`. This doesn't seem natural, but works. This is an expensive operation, especially if `List<T>` is large.

My question title was not the best, what I was striving for was an example showing a better way to do this.

Comment: Besides `ToString()` I don't see any virtual methods in `List<T>`, so inheriting from it is probably generally not a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reader.ReadStuff()` returns `List<Foo>` - but you are trying to assign it to an object of type `SomeList<Foo>` which inherits from `List<Foo>`. This doesn't work because `List<Foo>` **is not a** `SomeList<Foo>` - it's the other way round.

Think about it - it is legal to return a `List<Foo>` object from `ReadStuff()` - then you are trying to access functionality on this object that is only available on `SomeList<Foo>` - this will break and that's why OOP doesn't allow you to do this - instances of a child class can be used where an instance of a parent class is expected - but you cannot use a parent class where a child class is expected.

Going back to your question title: `SomeList<T>` : `List<T>` can't be cast as `List<T>`? Yes that's possible, but you are trying to cast `List<T>` to `SomeList<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

All instances of SomeList are instances of List. However, not all instances of List are instances of SomeList. That is what the second assignment is doing. reader.ReadStuff() returns a List, not a SomeList. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you're not casting an instance of `SomeList<Foo>` to `List<Foo>`, you're trying to cast a `List<Foo>` to a `SomeList<Foo>`. You're going from less specific to more specific, which doesn't work. It should work the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

change this code

```
 SomeList<Foo> aBetterList = reader.ReadStuff() 

 to 
SomeList<Foo> aBetterList = reader.ReadStuff()  as SomeList<Foo>; 

before using 
    if(aBetterList !=null) {}
```